# How to add an element inside another element which was added in the same function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html-table, queryselector

I am making a website project and I'm trying to make a function that will add new rows (`<tr>`) into an already existing empty table (`<table>`) and create cells (`<td>`) inside these rows containing informantion from a .json file. The first row contains certain dates and the first cell in every other row contains names of people.

Everything works just fine except for one thing. I want to add cells that fill the rest of the table. I will put some info about the people's schedules in those cells. I wanted to do it in the same function so that everything is added together right away but for some reason this specific part doesn't work.

Here's an example of the JavaScript code:

```
for(let x in namesArray){
      let tr = document.createElement('tr')
      tr.className = "plan";
      tr.innerHTML= "<th class='name'>"+namesArray[x]+"</th>";
      document.querySelector('tbody').appendChild(tr);
};
     
for(let i = 0; i < amountOfDates; i++)
{
      document.querySelectorAll(".plan").forEach(function(y){
      let td = document.createElement('td');
      td.className = "class_plan";
      y.appendChild(td);
      });


document.querySelectorAll(".class_plan").forEach(function(x){ 
      let span = document.createElement('span');
      span.className = "description";
      x.appendChild(span);
});
```

When I run the code the table works fine. The names are displayed properly, but it seems that the rest of the code doesn't work.

From my understanding, the code doesn't register any elements with the class ".plan" which is why the other cells are not displayed in the table. I'm not sure how to overcome this problem though.

This is how the table should've looked like:

|  | Date 1 | Date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Name 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

But instead the cells don't show up at all.

I've tried separating this code into two different functions, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you share the `html` of your expected outcome?

Comment: I think you will need to nest the td loops inside the tr loops and append each `td` to the current `tr`. querySelector works on the document, and your tr is not appended. Instead of trying to append to `y` from `forEach(function(y)`, append directly to the reference `tr` used to create the row element.

Comment: Your statement: *"but instead it looks like this"* is false because nowhere in your code you have anything like `--------`. Mind to share some minimal HTML and your data?

Comment: I think I overlooked where you did append tr to the document body. will look again.

Comment: Where is your `Cell 1` etc data stored? Currently I could only reproduce this example: https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/u3fmc4zn/ - and it's not our task to guesswork, instead: [edit] and create a [mcve].

Comment: OK, I think the problem is that your first block is appending a `tr` which you have already filled with `th` cells. The next blocks are appending `td` cells to the `tr` which already has `th` cells. I would nest the cell loops inside each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
for(let x in namesArray){
      let tr = document.createElement('tr')
      tr.className = "plan";
      tr.innerHTML= "<th class='name'>"+namesArray[x]+"</th>";

      for(let i = 0; i < amountOfDates; i++)
      {
          let td = document.createElement('td');
          td.className = "class_plan";
          let span = document.createElement('span');
          span.className = "description";
          td.appendChild(span);
          tr.appendChild(td);
      }
      document.querySelector('tbody').appendChild(tr);

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your TD elements inside your initial each loop (where yo ucreate your rows):

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

// My task:

const namesArray = ["Name 1", "Name 2"];
const amountOfDates = 2;

const elTable = el("#myTable");
const elTbody = el("tbody", elTable);

namesArray.forEach((name) => {

  const elTR = elNew("tr", {className: `plan`});
  const elTH = elNew("th", {className: `name`, textContent: name});

  elTR.append(elTH);

  for (let i = 0; i < amountOfDates; i++) {
    const elTD = elNew("td", { className: `class_plan`, textContent: `Cell ${ i+1 }`});
    elTR.append(elTD);
  }

  elTbody.append(elTR);
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Date 1</th>
      <th>Date 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```